# Match Canvas with Main Camera - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, uilabel

I want to use the Canvas and UI Text to constantly show the score of my game on the top right corner of the screen. How can I initialize the Canvas so that its position and dimensions perfectly match the border of the camera? (2D Setup)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

To see the canvas fit into the camera's size in the scene, change the `Canvas` component's `Render Mode` to `Screen Space - Camera`, and drag the camera from the hierarchy to it.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! One more thing to add - if your buttons are not visible in the game and go behind the background/sprites in your game window -> then click on the Canvas object and change "Order in Layer" to be some big number - e.g. 100. It has to be bigger number than the order number (Z coord - index) than your background/objects so that you can see it in the game scene. Cheers!

Comment: But this will not work properly if you have Pixel Perfect Camera component with Upscale Render option on it